# UCanAccess Exception UCAExc:::3.0.0 needs column or cannot drop sole column of table

Tags: ucanaccess

I am attempting to use UCanAccess to build a program to help me script some Access Database queries. Ultimately I want daily reports generated from a cron job. My couple of test cases to connect to said database give the following exception: UCAExc:::3.0.0 needs column or cannot drop sole column of table.

I'm a dabbler in databases, and this database is maintained by some other part of the company's organization.

The exception is thrown on the getConnection call.

> Output of console.sh after compact and repair: Cannot execute:CREATE 
>   CACHED TABLE EMPL() needs column or cannot drop sole column of table
>   Loaded Tables:
>
> Loaded Queries:
>
> Loaded Indexes:
>
> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.0 needs
>   column or cannot drop sole column of table    at
>   net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:258)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)  at
>   net.ucanaccess.console.Main.main(Main.java:145) Caused by:
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: needs column or cannot drop sole
>   column of table   at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)   at
>   net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet.exec(LoadJet.java:1416)     at
>   net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet.access$000(LoadJet.java:71)     at
>   net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.createSyncrTable(LoadJet.java:481)
>     at
>   net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.createSyncrTable(LoadJet.java:411)
>     at
>   net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.createTable(LoadJet.java:807)
>     at
>   net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.createTable(LoadJet.java:761)
>     at
>   net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.createTables(LoadJet.java:942)
>     at
>   net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.loadTables(LoadJet.java:1036)
>     at
>   net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.access$2900(LoadJet.java:273)
>     at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet.loadDB(LoadJet.java:1479)  at
>   net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:243)
>     ... 3 more Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: needs column or
>   cannot drop sole column of table  at
>   org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileCreateTableBody(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileCreateTable(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileCreate(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)    ... 16 more UCAExc:::3.0.0
>   needs column or cannot drop sole column of table

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us Java code for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates your problem. If the failure occurs when you connect to the database (`DriverManager.getConnection()`) then try doing a "Compact and Repair Database" in Access itself. If the problem persists then please run "console.bat" or "console.sh" from the same folder that contains the main UCanAccess JAR file, and then update your question to show us the results.

Comment: The problem does occur when I connect to the database. I attempted a compact and repair, but it caused the same problem. Here is the output from console.sh:

Comment: Try running the Java code [here](http://pastebin.com/ftZZFgju) against your database file and let us know how many columns it finds in your table. If your table really has zero (0) columns then it is not a valid Access table.

Comment: While I didn't use your code exactly, I took the template and learned a alot about this mess I'm attempting to interface to. There is a least one table with 0 columns. There are also tables which link to other files with windows network paths. I'm running this on a linux box. I have a handful of problems to solve, and I am going to have to talk to the maintainer of that access database file. Thanks for the pointers Gord!

Comment: Apparently the what I'm pointing to is a access front end (mdb file) for the actual ms-sql server. the particular table I want to query against is a linked table which does not show up when I list the tables with jackcess.

Answer (score 0):

UCanAccess will throw an exception when opening a database if it contains a table with no columns defined.

A table with no columns is not a valid table. Access itself will not allow us to save such a table ...

[image: NoSave.png]

... however it is possible to make such a table using DDL as in the following VBScript

```vbs
Option Explicit
Dim con
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\__tmp\31886535.accdb"
On Error Resume Next
con.Execute "DROP TABLE BadTable"
On Error Goto 0
con.Execute "CREATE TABLE BadTable (foo INT)"
con.Execute "ALTER TABLE BadTable DROP COLUMN foo"
con.Close
```

To avoid the error when opening the database with UCanAccess, simply open the database in Access and delete the table that has no columns defined.